# How to rearrange SQL table: ID to last ID

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a problem; I have a table called items in my database with contents like  `id`, `allowComments`, `fromUserId`, `category`, `categoryTitle`, `price`, `likesCount`, `imagesCount`, `viewsCount`, `reviewsCount` etc.

I want to be able to rearrange my desired `id` to be the latest `id`, and carry the rest upwards.

Here's an example:

```
id  allowComments   fromUserId  category    categoryTitle     price

1        1              1          3            Phone         20000
2        1              1          5            Car           100000
3        1              5          2            Console       20000
4        1              2          1            Fashion       100
5        0              1          3            Phone         12000
6        1              2          3            Phone         21300
```

Etc.

So my question is, how can I use PHP to make `id` `3` become the last `id`, and sort the other IDs to move up in an orderly fashion?

Lets just say this is my php file to fetch the content from database

```
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>category</th>
                                <th>price</th>
                                <th>cATEGORY ID </th>
                                <th>fromUserId</th>
                                <th>EDIT </th>
                                <th>REFRESH </th>

                            </tr>

                            <?php $k=1; while($get=mysql_fetch_array($insertionquery)) {?>

<td><?php echo $get['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $get['categoryTitle'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $get['price']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $get['category']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $get['fromUserId']; ?></td>

<td><a href="editmenu.php?EDITC=<?php echo $get['id']?>"></a></td>
<td><a href="refresh.php?REFRESH=<?php echo $get['id']?>"></a></td>
```

Comment: moving id's is usually considered a bad idea for databases, how about adding a sort column instead?

Comment: First set the id to the last id: `UPDATE table_name SET id=(SELECT max(id)+1) FROM table_name WHERE id=3;`. Next reset the auto_increment counter with: `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Comment: can you please write the code in form of php file am a bit confused

Comment: I can't because I do not know if you're using PDO or MySQLi. You're not providing any of your code. And I also do not know your table name.

Comment: If you can give me that information, I can write you some example code.

Comment: Am using mysql not mysqli, have updated the php file for fetching data

Comment: Ai. `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for over 3 years now. When you use the latest PHP, it won't even work anymore. Can you just give me the name of your mysql table please? I'll write you some stuff that will teach you how to use PDO (it's really easy) and answer your question at the same time :)

Comment: the name of my database is globali2_olx and the table is items

Comment: Alright. I'll be working on it. Will take some time so pls be a bit patient :)

Answer (score 1):

Tested the Above Script did not work so i did so research and found out something is wrong. use the below code i tested it and it worked

```
<?php

/* Database info */
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'globali2_olx';

/* Set DSN and Options */
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
$options = array(
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);

/* Instantiate the PDO object */
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

/* Set ID */
$id = 25;

/* Set query */

$query = "update location j1 inner join location j2 on j1.id <= j2.id 
 left outer join location j3 on j2.id < j3.id 
 set j1.id = j2.id + 1 
 where j1.id = $id and j3.id is null";

/* Prepare query */
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

/* Bind values */
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

/* Execute query */
try {
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

/* Set query */
$query = 'ALTER TABLE location AUTO_INCREMENT = 1';

/* Query database */
try {
    $pdo->query($query);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

?>
```

or you can use this simple code

```
<?php


include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/config.php");

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);


 $id = 128;

$Sql_Query = "update product set id=3 where id=1";

$Sql_Query = "update product j1 inner join product j2 on j1.id <= j2.id 
 left outer join product j3 on j2.id < j3.id 
 set j1.id = j2.id + 1 
 where j1.id = $id and j3.id is null";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
 echo 'Record Updated Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, in the code below I'm commenting everything you need to know. It's important that you read this so you understand how it all works! I'm also leaving you this link: [PHP Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) so you can learn more about PDO and Prepared Statements in a more user friendly environment. At the bottom of this question you can find the code without all the comments to keep it more clear.

Keep in mind that you need to set the correct database information at the top of the code.

**Code with explanation in comments:**

```
<?php

/* Database info */
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'globali2_olx';

/* First we set up some information for our PDO object */
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);

/* Next we try to instantiate the PDO object and see if we can connect to the database */
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
}
/* Here we'll catch any database connection errors and output them so we know what's going on */
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

/* Now lets try to change row id 3 to the last row id */

/* First we setup our query */
$query = 'UPDATE items SET id=(SELECT max(id)+1) FROM items WHERE id = :id';

/* As you can see, we don't have the number 3 in there. Instead, we have a
   placeholder ':id'. This is because we're going to use Prepared Statements.
   They are not needed for this case, but I want to show how to do this
   because you do need them if you want to insert data that's provided by a user.
   This is to prevent SQL injection. SQL injection is very easy and allows
   visitors to your website to completely delete your database if you don't
   protect yourself against it. This will do just that. */

/* So lets prepare our query first */
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

/* Set ID */
$id = 3;

/* Now we're going to bind the data to the placeholder */
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

/* Now all that's left to do is execute it so our database gets updated */
try {
    $stmt->execute();
}
/* Again, catch any errors in our query and output them */
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

/* Next we need to re-arrange the id's */

/* First we setup our query */
$query = 'ALTER TABLE items AUTO_INCREMENT = 1';

/* Again, Prepared Statements are not nessesary here. So I'm gonna show
   you how to do it without them. */

/* All we have to do is query the database directly */
try {
    $pdo->query($query);
}
/* Again, catch any errors in our query and output them */
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

?>
```

**Clean Code:**

```
<?php

/* Database info */
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'globali2_olx';

/* Set DSN and Options */
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);

/* Instantiate the PDO object */
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

/* Set query */
$query = 'UPDATE items SET id=(SELECT max(id)+1) FROM items WHERE id = :id';

/* Prepare query */
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

/* Set ID */
$id = 3;

/* Bind values */
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

/* Execute query */
try {
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

/* Set query */
$query = 'ALTER TABLE items AUTO_INCREMENT = 1';

/* Query database */
try {
    $pdo->query($query);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    return $error;
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Am getting error like this                                                                                       Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\kobobay\admin\refresh.php on line 33                                                                                           which is   $stmt->bindParam(':id', 3);

Comment: @Sir-myke It should be fixed now.

Comment: @Sir-myke Or now it should be fixed. I forgot to fix both codes. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it stopped showing error but it do not rearrange the id in the database. it still remains the same way

Comment: please reply. the code did not update or rearrange the sql ?

Comment: @Sir-myke It's impossible for me to know what's going on at this point. The code should work fine. So something else must be causing issues. The only way for me to know would to see it for myself. And that would mean a Teamviewer session. It's up to you whether you want that or not.

Comment: how can i do the teamviewer session am testing it offline using xampp before i upload

Comment: Well you would need to tell me at what time you'll be online because we need to be online at the same time for it.

Comment: time varies from countries so dont know what to say

Comment: @Sir-myke So include your timezone? Or if it helps: It's now 2 AM here. You made that last comment 3 hours ago. So you made that comment around 11 PM for me.

Answer (score 0):

Study the code and use the one best for you. modify the table and it all works

```
UPDATE jobs j1
INNER JOIN jobs j2 ON j1.worker_id <= j2.worker_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs j3 ON j2.worker_id < j3.worker_id 
SET j1.worker_id = j2.worker_id + 1 
WHERE j1.worker_id = 3 AND j3.worker_id IS NULL;
```

- j1 is the row you want to change, based on the condition in the WHERE clause.
- j2 is the set of rows with a worker_id greater or equal to j1.
- j3 is the set of rows with a greater worker_id than j2 (when j2 has the greatest worker_id in the table, there is no row for j3, so j3.* will be NULL).
- j2 therefore has the greatest worker_id, so use its value + 1.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table jobs (id serial primary key, worker_id int);
mysql> insert into jobs (worker_id) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

mysql> select * from jobs;
+----+-----------+
| id | worker_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         2 |
|  3 |         3 |
|  4 |         4 |
|  5 |         5 |
+----+-----------+

mysql> update jobs j1 inner join jobs j2 on j1.worker_id <= j2.worker_id 
 left outer join jobs j3 on j2.worker_id < j3.worker_id 
 set j1.worker_id = j2.worker_id + 1 
 where j1.worker_id = 3 and j3.worker_id is null;

mysql> select * from jobs;
+----+-----------+
| id | worker_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         2 |
|  3 |         6 |
|  4 |         4 |
|  5 |         5 |
+----+-----------+
```

It works regardless of the value we want to change:

```
mysql> update jobs j1 inner join jobs j2 on j1.worker_id <= j2.worker_id 
 left outer join jobs j3 on j2.worker_id < j3.worker_id 
 set j1.worker_id = j2.worker_id + 1 
 where j1.worker_id = 5 and j3.worker_id is null;

mysql> select * from jobs;
+----+-----------+
| id | worker_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         2 |
|  3 |         6 |
|  4 |         4 |
|  5 |         7 |
+----+-----------+
```

And it works even if we're changing the row that already has the highest value in the table:

```
mysql> update jobs j1 inner join jobs j2 on j1.worker_id <= j2.worker_id 
 left outer join jobs j3 on j2.worker_id < j3.worker_id 
 set j1.worker_id = j2.worker_id + 1 
 where j1.worker_id = 7 and j3.worker_id is null;

mysql> select * from jobs;
+----+-----------+
| id | worker_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         2 |
|  3 |         6 |
|  4 |         4 |
|  5 |         8 |
+----+-----------+
```